# JSR311 deployment issue in weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c, jsr311

I have developed a web application(spring mvc , webservices) and tried deployed in tomcat 7, and weblogic 10.3.6. currently we are trying in weblogic 12c (12.1.1). the deployement was successfull. but when tried to invoke a page it giving below exception.

Attached the Jars used

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.12.jar
bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
castor-1.2.jar
castor-core-1.3.1.jar
castor-xml-1.3.1.jar
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
classmate-0.5.4.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.8.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-email-1.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-vfs2-2.0.jar
cxf-api-2.4.3.jar
cxf-bundle-2.4.3.jar
cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.4.3.jar
cxf-common-utilities-2.4.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dozer-5.4.0.jar
dwr.jar
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar
geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.1.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
icommons-base-1.3.0.jar
icommons-xml-1.4.0.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
jackson-core-lgpl-1.7.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.7.4.jar
jandex-1.0.3.Final.jar
jasper-impl-3.7.1.jar
jasperreports-4.5.0.jar
javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
jettison-1.3.jar
jetty-continuation-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-http-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-io-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-security-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-server-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jetty-util-7.4.5.v20110725.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
joda-time-1.6.2.jar
jra-1.0-alpha-4.jar
js-1.7R2.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
junit-4.4.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mail-1.4.jar
maven-scm-api-1.4.jar
maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar
maven-scm-provider-svnexe-1.4.jar
mimepull-1.4.jar
mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar
neethi-3.0.1.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
velocity-1.7.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
wss4j-1.6.3.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
xmlschema-core-2.0.1.jar
xmlsec-1.4.5.jar
xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar
```

and exception is

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
at weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:105)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:564)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:471)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
```

Answer (score 0):

while working with `JSR 311`
you need atleast one class annotated with `@Path`.

please create one test controller/class with `@Path` annotation.

Comment: but i haven't done such thing while deploying it in weblogic 11g. is it possible to stop jersey scanning resources.

Comment: place your web.xml if haven't any problem.

Comment: It worked when i installed jersey bundle (available in common/deploylable-binaries) as a shared libary and referred it in weblogic.xml. But need to know whether it would be possible without this work around ?